# Ability to dynamically hide / show elements on a page using knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

EDIT: I updated my binding based on the feedback.

I have a sub page on my web application wherein I need the ability to dynamically hide / show elements on that page based on user selected filtering options. In order to do so, I have written a custom binding like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customVisible = {
   update: function(element, valueAccessor){
            var params = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var show = params.method(params.data, params.searchText());
            ko.bindingHandlers.visible.update(element, function() { return show; });
        }
    };
```

The html markup for it is like this:

```
<div class="form-group" data-bind="foreach: objects">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-7 col-xs-12" data-bind="customVisible: {data: $data, method: $parent.filterSyncedObjects, searchText: $parent.searchText}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the markup of the input box:

```
<input  type="search" data-bind="value: searchText, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" placeholder="Enter A name to search">
```

'filterSearchObjects' is the method that returns true or false depending on whether the search matches and 'searchText' is an observable containing the user entered text. Here is my question:

Why isn't the customVisible.update function being fired when the value of 'searchText' changes?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is `searchText` a `ko.observable`? if so, should not be `var show = params.method(params.data, params.searchText());`?

Comment: Thank you. But it still doesn't answer my question: "Why isn't the update not being fired?"

Comment: Edit: Thank you huocp. That was it!